# How can i load data from a spreadsheet to an html using google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to pass information that is in my current SpreadSheet to an HTML file i have, the html was made with google app script, if someone can guide me with this it would be very helpful. I'm i little bit lost about this

***Html***

```html
<body>
    <!--3.x snippet-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--2.x snippet-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--1.x snippet-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Source -->
    <!-- Google Hosted Libraries: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries#jquery -->
  <script>
    window.writeData = function() {
    var userInformation = document.getElementById('form');
    google.script.run.registerUser(userInformation);
  };
  </script>
  <blockquote class="trello-card">
    <a href="" id="myLink">Trello Card</a>
  </blockquote>
  <script src="https://p.trellocdn.com/embed.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myname => {
    var elem = document.getElementById('myLink');
    elem.href += myname;
    console.log('This is myname:' + myname);
    }).getCardById();
  </script>
</body>
```

***Function that should return the information of the sheet***

```js
function getCardById(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSp = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = activeSp.getActiveSheet();
  var linkCol = activeSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  //Logger.log(' LINKCOL:' + linkCol);
  return linkCol;
}
```

***Function that show the html***

```js
function seeCard() {
 var templateFileId = '1upA3JHioEyxLScebasmsmwXW-SxsiKaPRznKLCKFYhw';
 var sheetName = 'Trello sheet';
 SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateFileId).copy(sheetName);
 var excel =  SpreadsheetApp.create("Probando un html interno a ver ")
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index') //index is the name of your HTML file
  .setTitle('Trello card')
  .setWidth(300);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showSidebar(html);

}
```

***Video of what is happening right now***

[video of the problem](https://www.screencast.com/t/Xnh80db6RRUh)

***Picture in the console ***

https://www.screencast.com/t/6tHH15yz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to use the value from `getCardById()` to the variable of `myname` using Google Apps Script and Javascript.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

Unfortunately, `google.script.run` doesn't return no values. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)) So in this case, please use `withSuccessHandler` as follows. When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myLink'),
var myname = google.script.run.getCardById(); 
elem.href +=  myname ;
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myname => {
  var elem = document.getElementById('myLink');
  elem.href = myname;
}).getCardById();
```

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: Yes, you understood what i want to do, but your answer is not working because the `href` doesn't change with the value of `myname` . You know why this could be happening?

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to confirm the value from `getCardById()`, when `console.log(myname)` is put to before `var elem = document.getElementById('myLink')`, what value will you see at the console?

Comment: The `console.log(myname)` said the information of the sheet i need

Comment: But really don't know why is not putting it to the `href`

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. About `not putting it to the href`, when you clicked the link, what result did you get?

Comment: When i click the `href` doesn't send me to a place it looks like the link doesn't contain anything

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you add your current script for replicating the issue in your question? By this, I would like to confirm it. How about this? By the way, If your script in your question modified by my answer is different from your tested script, I might not be able to replicate your issue. Because I can know only your script in your question. Please be careful this.

Comment: Perfect let me put all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210832/discussion-between-rinzler21-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for adding your current script. When I saw your script, I could confirm that my answer is not correctly reflected. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct reason of your current issue, please modify `elem.href += myname;` to `elem.href = myname;`, and test it again? By this, what result will you get?

Comment: I change it so the link looks fine, but still doesn't send me where i want, what i mean whit this that when i click the link doesn't go to anywhere, but if i see the link attached to the `href` is correct

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, when you directly access to the URL of `console.log(myname)` using your browser, what result will you get?

Comment: Let me put a video of what happen

Comment: See the video in the question

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the reason of your issue from your video. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When you clicked the URL on the sidebar, can you see the error at the console of browser? Or when your HTML is modified from `<a href="" id="myLink">Trello Card</a>` to `<a href="" id="myLink" target="_blank">Trello Card</a>`, what result will you get? Because I thought that your URL might not be opened in the sidebar.

Comment: This is one of the errors: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED`

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the reason of your issue from your replying. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. By the way, can I ask you about the result of above modification?

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for replying. When your HTML is modified from `<a href="" id="myLink">Trello Card</a>` to `<a href="" id="myLink" target="_blank">Trello Card</a>`, what result will you get?

Comment: Thanks to that the link works right now, thanks for that!,the problem i see is to embed the trello card is having problems with that, when i put the link manually worked perfectly

Comment: @Rinzler21 Thank you for replying. From your sample video and your replyign, I could confirm that the value of `linkCol` could be retrieved at the Javascript side by the proposed modification. But about your current issue, I also think that the URL is the reason of your issue. This is the same thinking with you. Unfortunately, about this issue, I think that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.